# How can I make Transmission stop limiting upload after downloading?

Tags: transmission

I often use Transmission to torrent at night, when I'm sleeping and can't adjust settings manually. Now what I'd like to do is make it respect my upload limit while torrents are still downloading (because an unlimited upload throttles download too much), but once I'm just seeding, I want my upload speed to be unlimited - there's no point in keeping the computer running for a measly 10 kB/s. Temporary speed limits can only be set by time, so they're only useful if I can accurately gauge when the torrents will finish downloading (which I can't).
Is there a way I can do this?
Thanks so much,
Betka

Comment: Have you tried rtorrent, or Ktorrent.  I prefer these options.

Comment: I'll check them out, thanks for the suggestion. I'm still open to to other answers :), in case anyone else stumbles across this question.